# Ansible amazon.aws.s3_object download object with wildcard or pattern?

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I'm using an Ansible playbook to download file(s) from AWS S3. The problem is the file name can change so I need to find it with a wildcard. When I tried including a wildcard in the path it threw a "no object found" error.

I tried the `prefix` parameter, but it threw an error that `object` is required. I looked at the [`s3_object`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/s3_object_module.html) documentation as well as [`s3_object_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/s3_object_info_module.html) and I can't find anything about using wild cards.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `list` for the `mode` parameter to get a list of items with a specified `prefix`, then in a second task downloaded those items:

```yaml
- name: Get list of items
  amazon.aws.s3_object:
    bucket: "{{ bucket }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    prefix: /object/path/prefix
    object: /object/path
    mode: list
  register: files

- name: Download items
  amazon.aws.s3_object:
    bucket: "{{ bucket }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    object: "{{ item }}"
    mode: get
  loop: "{{ files.s3_keys }}"
```